# $F(\alpha)$ is isomorphic to the field $F(x)$ of rational functions over $F$ in the indeterminate $x$ where $\alpha$ is transcendental over $F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, extension-field, transcendental-numbers, algebraic-numbers

> Q.$(a)$ If $\alpha$ is transcendental over a field $F$, then show that
> $(i)$ the map $\mu : F[x] → F[\alpha],f (x) \mapsto f (\alpha)$ is an
> isomorphism; $(ii)$ $F(\alpha)$ is isomorphic to the field $F(x)$ of
> rational functions over $F$ in the indeterminate $x$. $(b)$ Show that
> the field $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ is isomorphic to the field $\mathbb{Q}(x)$
> of rational functions over $\mathbb{Q}$.

First of allWhat is the meaning of indeterminate $x$?

By the way hers what I have tried

$(i)$ Now clearly the map $\mu : F[x] → F[\alpha],f (x) \mapsto f (\alpha)$ is an epimorphism. If two polynomial expressions $f_1(\alpha)$ and $f_2(\alpha)$ are equal in $F(\alpha)$, their coefficients must be equal term by term, otherwise, the difference $f_1(α) − f_2(\alpha)$ will give a polynomial equation in α with coefficients, not all zero. This contradicts our assumption that $\alpha$ is transcendental over $F$. This shows that the map $\mu$ is a bijection and hence it is an isomorphism under usual operations of polynomials.

$(ii)$ Define the map $\varphi : F(\alpha) → F(x),\frac{f (\alpha)}{g(\alpha} \mapsto \frac{f (x)}{g(x)}$. Exactly the same reason as we have in $(i)$ holds for $(ii)$, so $ \varphi $ is an isomorphism

$(b)$ if we take $\alpha=\pi$ which is transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$, from $(ii)$ we have the desired result.

It's quite absurd that $\mathbb{Q}(\pi) \cong \mathbb{Q(x)}$ because $\mathbb{Q(x)}$ is a ratio of polynomials. Or am I misunderstood something?

Is my reasoning correct? Or there is another better way to prove this.  Any help is appreciated thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no mistake in your logic. The result you are calling absurd should be the reason why numbers $\alpha$ that don't satisfy a polynomial over a field $K$ are said to be *transcendental*. They literally transcend the comprehension of the field $K$. The field $K$ has no idea how to think about $\alpha$. Another way to interpret your isomorphism is as the field $\mathbb Q$ saying "I literally searched every polynomial expression and even rational expression that $\pi$ might satisfy.. and I failed to find anything". This is basically just one step away from the definition of transcendental numbers.

If you ask the abstract field of rational numbers $\mathbb Q$ how it thinks about the alien number $\sqrt2$, they will tell you "Well it's a number that I don't have within but when you square it, you get a number $2$ which I am very familiar with." If you ask it the same question about $\pi$, it will tell you: "I have no freaking clue. I know as much about it as I do about an indeterminate $x$. Neither of them satisfy any relationship that I am familiar with". So as far as the field $\mathbb Q$ is concerned, transcendental numbers (like $e$ and $\pi$ and $\tau$ etc ) basically behave like indeterminates $x$.

Now, why then, do we feel that $\pi$ is something very concrete and much less ethereal than something like an $x$? It's because we are so used to thinking of the field $\mathbb Q$ embedded in $\mathbb R$ which carries a natural metric structure( i.e. distance ) which lets us think things like: "Oh $\pi$ is kind of close to $3$ or even closer to $\frac{31}{10}$. But this is all additional metric structure we get by the embedding $\mathbb Q \hookrightarrow \mathbb R$. In fact, without this embedding, you cannot even define $\pi$. The object $\mathbb Q$ in isolation with only it's field structure knows none of this. As far it is concerned, transcendental numbers behave like indeterminates. In fact, if you take a look back at parts i and ii, this is what you have proven!

Comment: Thanks. Very insightful answer.

Comment: +1 for the nice answer. It conveys the meaning of transcendental in very clear manner.

Comment: @arkady , 2 week passed since you have answered this question,  but I have a question about the informations that $\mathbb{Q}$ has, you are saying $\mathbb{Q}$ does not have a clue about $\pi,e$ but we can express $\pi$ as $\pi=4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$ or as a continued fraction and similarly $e=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}$, so we are expressing them infinite sum of rational numbers. So why don't then $\mathbb{Q}$ has  no clue about $\pi \ or \ e?$

Comment: Unwind the definitions and you will find an absolute value/metric lurking there. Rings and fields natively understand finite sums. Infinite sums are limits of finite sums. The definition of $\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i = L$ is that for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists $N>0$ such that for any $n>N$ we have $| \sum_{i=0}^n a_i - L| < \epsilon$. There's your metric $| \cdot |$ that's not specified in the ring/field axioms.

Comment: @Arkady yeah again thanks

Answer (score 1):

If $F(x)\rightarrow F(\alpha):f(x)\mapsto f(\alpha)$ is an isomorphism, then the kernel is $\{0\}$. Thus there is no algebraic equation $g(\alpha)=0$ for some non-zero polynomial $g(x)$. This means that $\alpha$ is not algebraic over $F$ and so can be viewed as an indeterminate over $F$.